# sas macro to delete all datasets from work lib clear all filename libname statements and delete user defined macro variables

Tags: sas, sas-macro

i need a generic macro SAS to delete all data-sets from work lib clear all file-name libname statements and delete user defined macro variables.

Comment: Try proc delete for deleting the datasets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
%macro clearALL;
/*delete macro variables*/
data delete;
set sashelp.vmacro;
where scope eq: 'G' and name ne: 'SYS';
run;
data _null_;
set delete;
call symdel(name);
run;

/*clear libnames and filenames*/
libname _ALL_ clear;
filename _ALL_ clear;
/*deletes all datasets from work*/
proc datasets lib=work kill noprint;
run;
%mend clearALL;
```

Comment: %macro cleanup;
proc datasets library = work nolist
kill;
quit;

proc sql noprint;
 select unique libname 
 into : mylibs separated by 'clear; libname'
 from dictionary.libnames
 where libname not in ('MAPS','SASHELP','SASUSER','WORK');
quit;
libname &mylibs clear;
%put "&mylibs";

proc sql noprint;
 select unique fileref 
 into : myfiles separated by  ' clear; filename '
 from dictionary.extfiles
where substr(fileref,1,1)^= '#'; 
quit;
filename &myfiles ; 
filename &mylibs clear ;
%put "&myfiles" ;
%mend cleanup;
%cleanup;